# How do I give an SqlConnection a string as the AttachDbFilename?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datasource

I'd like to have a string be used as the `AttachDbFilename` in my `SqlConnection`.

However when I feed it a string it doesn't work and just gives me a null or invalid connection/failure. How do I properly provide `AttachDbFilename` as a string value in place of the normal set path?

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string databasePath = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName;

    SqlConnection dataBaseConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=databasePath;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `databasePath` inside the string literal so right now you are trying to attach with a Db Filename of "databasePath", which I'm assuming doesn't exist. One way you could do this is to use `string.Format`, so you would do something like this

```
string databasePath = openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName;
SqlConnection dataBaseConnection = new SqlConnection(string.Format(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True", databasePath);
```

Or, for something even more organized, you could use the [SQLConnectionStringBuilder](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlconnectionstringbuilder&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS799US799&oq=sqlconnectionstringbuilder&aqs=chrome..69i57.3792j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) class to build a connection string for you, and then just set the AttachDbFilename property of the builder to the string that you want.

Comment: I tried that code and the dataBaseConnection is stale and the debugger says "The value of this item is stale due to a problem that occured while evaluating it".